# How to limit number of created custom object records in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-flow

I currently have a project with two custom objects 'Registration' and 'Team' as a Master-Detail Relationship.
I'd like to set a limit for each record of 'Registration' the user can add a max of 2 records inside his 'Team'.
I've thought about making a Flow to replace the 'New' button where it looks up the number of active related records of that object and if it's >=2 shows a message, is there any way to do this without Flows?

I know it would be possible using Flows, but I'd like some simpler resolution if it's actually possible.

Comment: 2 total (across all users) or max 2 per user? Total should be doable with rollup summary field doing COUNT and then a val rule or maybe conditional rendering logic for the button (dynamic actions it's called I think). Per user bit messier, may need flow or bit of coding